# Facebookログインについて

Tags: monaca, facebook

Facebook開発者サイトにてアプリ登録し以下を設定しましたが
MonacaIDEにて、プレビューを行うと下記のようなエラーが出てログインできません。
ご教授ください。

App Domains：ide.monaca.mob
サイトURL：https://ide.monaca.mobi/preview/54e7192ffd?????????????

指定されたURLは、アプリケーションの設定で許可されていません。: 指定されたURLの中にアプリの設定で認められないものが含まれています。ウェブサイトまたはキャンバスのURLと一致しているか、ドメインがアプリのドメインのサブドメインである必要があります。

Answer (score 1):

[日本語のFacebook開発者サイトにてこのエラーを見えたりませんでしたが、](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/Japanese/#adsapi)

[英語のFacebook開発者サイトにてこのエラーが載っています。](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/error-reference)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

セキュリティのチェックリストを一度確認をされたらどうでしょうか？
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security